Difficulty connecting to VPN in Budgie 22.04
I need to connect to a VPN from my Ubuntu (22.04.4) Budgie (10.6.1). I followed these instructions, and I think I got OpenVPN installed and running. Then I imported the .ovpn file and accepted all the defaults (automatic IPv4 and IPv6).
However, when I try to enable the VPN as shown below, the switch will not turn on.

I also tried this link, but it was not for Budgie and I could not find the System menu.
To be clear, I am trying to connect to a university server from my desktop. The .ovpn was provided by that university.
Any idea what I am missing here in order to connect to this VPN?

Are you trying to set up OpenVPN server or the client? If client, where did you get the .ovpn file? Did you create this file for your own VPN server following the guide or did you get the file from a commercial VPN service provider, or did you get it from your place of employment?

I am trying to connect through my client (Ubuntu Budgie) to an OpenVPN server someone else has setup. I got the .ovpn file from the person who setup the server (a university, not my employer).

Please add these details to your question.
